# Permutations and number of permitted combinations three percentages which must add up to 100%

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

is there a simple way to find the number of combinations of three percentage values with discrete step sizes which add up to 100%?

Example:

`Variable 1: Min: 10%, Max: 60%, Stepsize:  5%
Variable 2: Min: 20%, Max: 70%, Stepsize:  5%
Variable 3: Min: 10%, Max: 50%, Stepsize: 10%`

Possible values:

`Variable 1: 10%,15%,20%,...,55%,60%
Variable 2: 20%,25%,30%,...,65%,70%
Variable 3: 10%,20%,30%,40%,50%`

I want to find the number of possible combinations of these values which add up to 100%, e.g.

10% Variable 1 + 20% Variable 2 + 10%Variable 3 -> not possible, sum not 100%

10% Variable 1 + 20% Variable 2 + 70%Variable 3 -> not possible, Variable 3 out of Range

10% Variable 1 + 40% Variable 2 + 50%Variable 3 -> possible

Comment: Is there any particular reason to formulate this with percentages rather than numbers?

Comment: no, not at all. the formulation just came from the application I thought about and came up with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use a generating function to solve this problem.

In your example, the answer you are looking for is the coefficient of $x^{100}$ in the expansion of

$(x^{10}+x^{15}+x^{20}+…+x^{60})(x^{20}+x^{25}+x^{30}+…+x^{70})(x^{10}+x^{20}+…+x^{50})$

You can divide this expression by $x^{40}$ to give

$(1+x^{5}+x^{10}+…+x^{50})^2(1+x^{10}+x^{20}+…+x^{40})$

Since we divided by, $x^{40}$, finding the coefficient of $x^{100}$ in the former expression is equivalent to finding the coefficient of $x^{60}$ in the latter.

Substituting $y=x^5$ yields $(1+y+y^{2}+…+y^{10})^2(1+y^{2}+y^{4}+…+y^{8})$ and we are now looking for the coefficient of $y^{12}$.

We can write the expression in closed form, then expand:

$(1+y+y^{2}+…+y^{10})^2(1+y^{2}+y^{4}+…+y^{8})\\={\left(\frac{1-y^{11}}{1-y}\right)}^2\left(\frac{1-y^{10}}{1-y^2}\right)\\=(1-y^{11})^2(1-y^{10})(1-y)^{-2}(1-y^2)^{-1}\\=(1-y^{10}-2y^{11}+2y^{21}+y^{22}-y^{32})(1+2y+3y^2+4y^3+…)(1+y^2+y^4+y^8+…)$

It suffices to compute the coefficient of $y^{12}$ in this expansion, which, if my calculations are correct, is $49 - 4 - 4 = 41$.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to have a look at it. My code says the result is 44.

Comment: 41 is correct. The list of combinations, courtesy of Mathematica: {{10,40,50},{10,50,40},{10,60,30},{10,70,20},{15,35,50},{15,45,40},{15,55,30},{15,65,20},{20,30,50},{20,40,40},{20,50,30},{20,60,20},{20,70,10},{25,25,50},{25,35,40},{25,45,30},{25,55,20},{25,65,10},{30,20,50},{30,30,40},{30,40,30},{30,50,20},{30,60,10},{35,25,40},{35,35,30},{35,45,20},{35,55,10},{40,20,40},{40,30,30},{40,40,20},{40,50,10},{45,25,30},{45,35,20},{45,45,10},{50,20,30},{50,30,20},{50,40,10},{55,25,20},{55,35,10},{60,20,20},{60,30,10}}

Comment: Alright, got the same result. My Variable 3 was still defined between 10% and 60% instead of 50%. This gives the additional results {10,30,60}, {15,25,60}, {20,20,60}

Comment: Now I wonder if it is possible to use this method in a code which is faster than just looping over all possibilities.

Comment: @krtek Maybe this can provide some insight? http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1913/recurrences-and-generating-functions-in-algorithms

Comment: @RogueAutodidact thanks, looks very interesting. I'll have a closer look at it, if I have some free time.